# How to tell feature vectors are sufficient for a graph neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graph-neural-network

Not sure the right terminology, but I am working on a node classification problem, and I am only able to obtain a training accuracy of 50% for my GNN (test accuracy is 40%).

It seems I should be able to overfit the model and achieve nearly 100% with the training data, but I assume the feature vectors are not adequate for what I am trying to learn with the model.

How could I verify this is the case? Is there an approach for determining if the feature space is adequate for the problem?